# Background color not inheriting

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.ribbon-left {left: 10px;top: 20px; width: 400px; height: 300px;position: absolute;}

    .css-table {display: table;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: red;}
    .css-row { display: table-row; }
    .css-cell {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle; }

    .ribbon-left-middle {width: 80%;bottom: 0;padding-left: 5px;position: relative; }
    .ribbon-left-middle-inner {top: 5px;position: absolute;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ribbon-left">
    <div class="css-table">
        <div class="css-row">
            <div class="css-cell ribbon-left-middle">
                <div class="ribbon-left-middle-inner">
                    <div class="productElements">Product elements</div>
                    <div class="productDescription">Product description</div>
                    <div class="productUsage">Product usage</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.ribbon-left {left: 10px;top: 20px; width: 400px; height: 300px;position: absolute;}

    .css-table {display: table;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: red;}
    .css-row { display: table-row; }
    .css-cell {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle; }

    .ribbon-left-middle {width: 80%;bottom: 0;padding-left: 5px;position: relative; }
    .ribbon-left-middle-inner {top: 5px;position: absolute;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ribbon-left">
    <div class="css-table">
        <div class="css-row">
            <div class="css-cell ribbon-left-middle">
                <div class="ribbon-left-middle-inner">
                    <div class="productElements">Product elements</div>
                    <div class="productDescription">Product description</div>
                    <div class="productUsage">Product usage</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my example. I have defined red background color to css table parent div. Why text doesn't have red background in child div's? Isn't background propagated to childs?

The same sample only that i have more than one "css-cell" div, the red background is there.
What should i change here?

Comment: You could set the background colour of the child elements to 'inherit'

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Background color is not inherited. Check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

It defaults to transparent, though, so it can look like its inherited.

However, you problem is here: `.ribbon-left-middle-inner {top: 5px;position: absolute;}`

By positioning the element absolute, its parent is empty and has no size. Use your browsers element inspector.

Change to: `.ribbon-left-middle-inner {top: 5px;}`

Comment: Thank you. When remove absolute, it works.
But totally the same example, only that I have 3 div's inside "css-row"
("css-cell ribbon-left-top", "css-cell ribbon-left-middle", "css-cell ribbon-left-bottom"), the background color is present in all divs. How is that possible?

Comment: Thanks :) Can we talk?